# App installation failed The application does not have a valid signature

Tags: ios, swift

When i run my app in IOS 9.3.2 it works fine.
But when i run same app on IOS 8.3 it gives following Error -

> "App installation failed:- The application does not have a valid signature."

This happends only when I install Swift application. When i install Objective c App with same profile and Certificate, it works fine. I am using Developer Certificate and XCODE version is 7.3

Answer (score 3):

If you are changing xcode to run in ios 8.3 then once clean the project and then try. sometime it works. If not using another xcode then also try after cleaning the project.

You can clean project by `command + shift + k` or from `product` select `clean`.

**Update:**

If you have folder references(If you have blue folders instead of yellow) then remove it and add everything in individual group.

For do that i advise to first make one copy of your project as backup and then do experiment.

If you have not much idea about folder reference and group then refer [this link](http://vocaro.com/trevor/blog/2012/10/21/xcode-groups-vs-folder-references/).

Hope this will help :)

Comment: I have checked with xcode 7.3.1 and clean it multiple times, But it dint solve my problem.

Comment: Check my update in answer

Comment: Not working. Tried this as well.. sometimes it installs in Iphone 5(ios 9.2.1) and fails to instal in iphone5s(ios 9.3.1) when installing through .ipa file .

Comment: A note to whomever may stumble across this answer, doing a clean resolved this for me.